# Rails app not sending emails after placing order and changing delivery status, it just breaks down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, vps

In an E store I'm building. The customer can buy items and the transaction goes through via braintree with out problems.

But when the customer place its order....things go bad... the app breaks.

rails gives an error page " We're sorry, but something went wrong."

this is the `.log`from the server

```
   I, [2017-05-19T22:23:10.127481 #22752]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2695ms (ActiveRecord: 7.7ms)
F, [2017-05-19T22:23:10.129139 #22752] FATAL -- :
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 587):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

and here is the `order_controller.rb`
the line 35 is `OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver`

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

include CurrentCart
before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]

def index
    @orders = Order.all? 
end

def new
    @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
 @random_no = rand(5)
 @random_image = @images[@random_no]

    if @cart.product_items.empty?
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Cart is Empty'
        return

    end
    @order = Order.new
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate

    @del_cost_euro = 20
end

def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        charge
        if @result.success?
            @order.add_product_items_from_cart(@cart)
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver  #this is line 35
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order'
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Please Check Your Cart'
            redirect_to root_url, alert: @result.message
            @order.destroy
        end
    else
        @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
        render :new
    end
end


def show

end


def destroy
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order deleted'
end

private

def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :country, :pick_up, :delivery)
end

def charge
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        amount: @cart.total_price_usd,
        payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce] )
end

end
```

For the backend I'm using `activeadmin`... after the order is placed, I can see the order in the Order panel at the back end, but when I want to change the `shipped` from `false`to `true` the app breaks again...

the customer is supposed to receive a mail about the order being shipped.. but it never gets sent

the `error log` says

```
I, [2017-05-20T13:50:26.645335 #19043]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
F, [2017-05-20T13:50:26.646495 #19043] FATAL -- :
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 587):
  app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Again the breaking has something to do with the sending of mails.

here is the `app/admin/order.rb`

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Order do

    permit_params :shipped

    after_update do |order|
        OrderNotifier.shipped(@order).deliver if order.shipped # Again the error is happening in the OrderNotifier

    end

    show do |order|

        panel 'Customer Details' do
            attributes_table_for order, :name, :email, :address, :city, :country, :created_at
        end

        panel 'Created ' do
            "#{time_ago_in_words order.created_at} ago"
        end


        panel 'Shipped ' do
            order.shipped
        end

        panel 'Order Details' do
            table_for(order.product_items) do 
                column 'Product' do |item|
                    item.product.title
                end
                column 'Quantity' do |item|
                    item.quantity
                end
                column 'Price Isl' do |item|
                    number_to_currency item.total_price_isl
                end
                column 'Price USD' do |item|
                    number_to_currency item.total_price_usd
                end
            end
        end

        panel 'Order Total USD' do 
            number_to_currency order.total_price_usd

        end

        panel 'Order Total Iskr' do 
            number_to_currency order.total_price_isl

        end

    end


end
```

So here is the `app/mailers/order_notifier`

```
 class OrderNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  default from: 'Hlín Reykdal Concept Store <store@hlinreykdal.com>'

  def received(order)
    @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Hlín Reykdal Concept Store'
  end


  def shipped(order)
   @order = order

    mail to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped'
  end
end
```

here is the `app/config/environment/production.rb`

```
    Rails.application.configure do
     config/application.rb.    
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'hlinreykdal.com'}
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USER"],
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    domain: "hlinreykdal.com",
    port: 587,
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

    Braintree::Configuration.environment = :production
    Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = ENV['merchant_id']
    Braintree::Configuration.public_key = ENV['public_key']
    Braintree::Configuration.private_key = ENV['private_key']

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 587 is typically reserved for SMTP, so you're right: this is email related: it sounds like the configured SMTP server isn't up and accepting connections. Resolve that and this error should go away.

Comment: Ok thanks, can I then install something like `Postfix` on the VPS? I thought it was all automatic, since the mail is via google suits

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I use a [delivery service](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/sendgrid-api/) for everything. I also use [platform-as-a-service for hosting](http://heroku.com/) Rails stuff. Way easier than wasting my time poking at AWS.

Comment: also, use `delayed_job` or some other similar gem to send emails asynchronously and avoid such errors/exceptions raised affecting UX.

Comment: Okokok... thanks all...I did some digging.... is it possible that digitalOcean is blocking port 587?  at leat according to this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/outgoing-connections-on-port-25-587-143-blocked-over-ipv6